# Multiple non-independent tests, how to determine post-test odds

Tags: independence, likelihood-ratio, odds

Let's say a patient receives two biomarker tests to help with diagnosis of a disease. Each test measures a different mechanism of the disease, but these two mechanisms are not independent, so the tests are not independent. The pre-test probability of disease is known. The positive likelihood ratio and other diagnostic characteristics (e.g. sensitivity, specificity, positive predictive value, negative predictive value, etc) are known for each test. **Given that the tests are not independent, how can you determine if performing both tests has added diagnostic value (i.e. performing an additional test increases the post-test odds of having the disease compared to performing only one test).** Examples would be helpful.